# No route matches {:action=>“show”, :controller=>“users”}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

i following happens, this is my Usercontroller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

def new
     @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to user_session_path
    else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
end

end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #redirect_to @user
end
end
```

in my routes.rb I have the following:

```
Estaciones::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => "static_pages#home"
match '/contact', :to=>'static_pages#contact'
match '/about', :to=>'static_pages#about'
devise_for :user
resources :user do
#resources :car
end
```

When I run it on my browser I get this:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I don't know why this happens???

Comment: your controller should be named `UsersController`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `User` object or at least the user id to the `link_to` method where you're creating the link that you're clicking. Try something like `<%= link_to user.name, user %>`

Also make sure that your controller is properly named e.g. `UsersController` (plural).

Comment: if I change the name of the controller, the application is going damaged

Comment: Along with controller also pluralize the symbol which you pass to defise_for method that is `devise_for :users`

Comment: now appears Routing Error

    uninitialized constant UsersController

Comment: You need to restart your server after renaming a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Rename both the file:

`'user_controller.rb'` => `'users_controller.rb'`

and the constant at the top:

`UserController` => `UsersController`

File names must match constants, and the convention is for models to be singular, and controllers to be plural (matching the table).

and try visiting

`/users/1`